# servlet execution error in eclipse

Tags: java

HTTP Status 404 - /Project/

---

type Status report

message /Project/

description The requested resource (/Project/) is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.16

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Project</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**this is the autogenerated web.xml in eclipse**

Comment: please post your code snippet. And describe your question rather than simply copy pasting the html error page.

Comment: You actually expect people to understand where is the problem by pasting just this? Well its not possible.

Comment: no error in code.. if i am running it in eclipse.. it should be executed and the url should be http://localhost:8080/Project/DemoServlet but insted it is http://localhost:8080/Project/ and then this error

Comment: have you put an index page in the WebContent folder?

Comment: no . i have developed a simple servlet by following a video tutorial. there was no mention of any such kind of index page

Comment: can you post your web.xml file by editing your question?

Comment: is this link working fine localhost:8080/Project/DemoServlet when you type it in the browser address bar?

Comment: yes the link http://localhost:8080/Project/DemoServlet is working . when i run the project this is the actual link which has to open

Comment: How about to configure the web application for servlet mapping?

Comment: no use even after configuring the web.xml file with servlet mapping

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a servlet and its mapping in your web.xml so that the server can call its `doGet` or `doPost` method when any request comes in for your servlet.
Add this in your web.xml
The comments describe each tag usage. You can remove the part `<!--  ..... -->` from each tag

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>  <!-- You can give any name -->
<servlet-class>com.abu.MyFirstServlet</servlet-class> Your servlet class's fully qualified name
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name> the name that you mentioned in the above tag
<url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern> the url for which the request must be sent to the servlet.
</servlet-mapping>
```

This means that whenever you type `http://localhost:8080/YourPorject/index.html` then the conatiner will call your servlet's `doGet` or `doPost` method. You should have a look at this [wiki page for gaining basic knowledge about servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 0):

you need to put one file in root directory from above list.

Comment: i have tried it.. the 404 error is not displayed but still the url remians http://localhost:8080/Project/ instead of http://localhost:8080/Project/DemoServlet

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: how it will know that you are asking for "DemoServlet" servlet. url will be stay  "localhost:8080/Project" till you are not requesting any resource. when you write "/DemoServlet" after your url then it go in web.xml and find "DemoServlet" and execute its code. you have to put there some logic of redirecting or forwarding.

Comment: @bahrep ok. i will be careful next time.